# What is the approach of message suppression implemented in veins/omnet simulation demo scenarios?

Tags: omnet++

In Veins demo simulation scenarios, vehicles broadcast event message to each other. However, in the events scheduled interface it shows that there is an erase of duplicate message?

Answer (score 0):

The [Veins example](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4a2/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L55) uses a dummy  implementation: each vehicle only relays a single message. Just to reinforce this point: This is **not** what you would put in any reasonable protocol.

Comment: Thank you so much Pr sommer for your reply ,i want to ask you is there any GeoCast or broadcast Protocol implemented in veins demo , is there any default supprssion technique implimented such as ( Slotted p-Persistence , Slotted 1-Persistence , Weighted p-Persistence ) ? . Thus , We would be grateful if you could answer me about this point .